# Parse Twitter Login

Tags: angularjs, twitter, parse-platform, satellizer

I am currently trying to develop an AngularJS application using Parse.com as backend. I have implemented email login and sign up features and now I want to implement Sign In With Twitter option.

I am using Parse JS SDK for the rest of my project but since JS SDK doesn't support twitter authorization yet, I found [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#configuration) angular module and I want to use it for both twitter and G+. But I don't know how to implement this module with Parse.

Alternatively I may also use Parse REST API to login with Twitter but Parse Docs only explains how to save the auth data coming from Twitter. I doesn't explain how can I get that auth data.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use Satellizer to log into Google or Twitter. Look at the Satellizer web site to do that. Then upon the authorize success handler you would send a a REST call from your UI (example /login/google or /login/twitter) with an `Authorization` header with the Bearer token. Example:

```
Authorization: Bearer sdkfhg0943fda4dss4fd
```

Your server can delegate a call to the appropriate API to get the user details from the token. In the case of Google:

```
varuri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token="+tokenContent;
```

In the case of Twitter, you'll need to add the `Authorization` header to the request (`Bearer sdf8sedn438ddfdsfsd`) and send a request to:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

I would then normalize the response from the auth provider on the server and sent it back to your Angular App.